# Customer analyzer with azure search to search strings multiple special characters

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have another question on Azure Search, I have an index called “branchorders-index” (schema attached). I have string field called “lowerCustomerPONbr” with custom analyzer as below:

```
  "analyzers": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
        "name": "SWMLuceneAlongWithCustomHyphenAnalyser",
        "tokenizer": "keyword_v2",
        "tokenFilters": [
            "lowercase"
        ],
        "charFilters": []
    }
]
```

Question: What would be the correct query for searching text “engg - test - umesh”? I want a single document on execution of the query. Here is the query I am trying:

```
$count=true&$select=lowerCustomerPONbr&search=lowerCustomerPONbr:/.*engg\ \-\ test\ \-\ umesh.*/

{
    "@odata.context": "https://abcd/indexes('branchorders-index')/$metadata#docs(lowerCustomerPONbr)",
    "@odata.count": 8,
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.score": 0.22780417,
            "lowerCustomerPONbr": "engg - test - umesh"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.027440047,
            "lowerCustomerPONbr": "sam-clc-test-3"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.025132125,
            "lowerCustomerPONbr": "sam-clc-test-4"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.019148104,
            "lowerCustomerPONbr": "sam-clc-test-1"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.019148104,
            "lowerCustomerPONbr": "030 test 17 april"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.018480092,
            "lowerCustomerPONbr": "sam-clc-test-2"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.018480092,
            "lowerCustomerPONbr": "dilip-qa-test"
        },
        {
            "@search.score": 0.015009361,
            "lowerCustomerPONbr": "030 eng-test"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Santosh, if you add [&queryType=full](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#designate-the-lucene-query-parser-for-query-execution), does this fix the issue?